# Add captions to photos which are positioned with Isotope

Tags: css, image, jquery-isotope, caption

I'm having a very hard time trying to add captions to the photos in my gallery. I don't know how to make the caption sit on top of the images. It's the gallery here https://memsmosaics.com/gallery.html

Right now I've put in 3 example captions which are meant to sit on top of the first 3 images: bat, bees & moth. As you can see each caption just goes below the previous like a normal block element.
[image]

Here's the html for these 3 images and captions:

```
<figure>
  <figcaption>bat</figcaption>
  <a href='../images_organised_large/art_for_sale/Bat. $450 .jpg' target=blank>
    <img src='../images_organised_small/art_for_sale/Bat. $450 .jpg' class='all forsale'>
  </a>
</figure>

<figure>
  <figcaption>bees</figcaption>
  <a href='../images_organised_large/art_for_sale/Cicardas 3. $1,500 .jpg' target=blank>
    <img src='../images_organised_small/art_for_sale/Cicardas 3. $1,500 .jpg' class='all forsale'>
  </a>
</figure>

<figure>
  <figcaption>moth</figcaption>
  <a href='../images_organised_large/art_for_sale/golden musical moth $1,200.jpg' target=blank>
    <img src='../images_organised_small/art_for_sale/golden musical moth $1,200.jpg' class='all forsale'>
  </a>
</figure>
```

I've tried floating the `<figure>` tags and giving them a width equal to the width of the images, but that doesn't solve it either. It may look like it does at first but as soon as you narrow the screen, the captions do not stay in plsce on top of the images. This CSS isn't in there now but it looked like this:

```
figcaption {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
```

I guess the solving this would require understanding better how Isotope works. Will be very grateful for any help!